# 2 column floating layout, does width have to be specified for left column

Tags: css

If one uses float:left to layout two columns, does the left column have to have a width specified?  Without a width assigned, when I shrink the width of the browser page, the second (main) column gets put underneath the left (navigation) column.  Is there a way to avoid this, without assigning a width?  If not, what is the least width spec's I need to add?  I.e. can I assign a fixed pixel width to the left column, and have the right column get the rest?

Thanks

-----  Addition -----

After trying various answers, noting their complexity, is there any reason not to just use a two column table?

Comment: Why are you trying to not specify a width?

Comment: I can assign a width to the left column if need be.  It just seems like it ought to be simple to specify that two divs, are to sit side by side, regardless of their width?  Is this not possible?

Comment: Also, please note this is a "template kind of page", so I don't know how wide the right (main) content will be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer does not match the original question, which indicates to use float:left, the "generation 2" css layout mechanism after tables.   However, after trying multiple variations and tweaks to the float:left layout given, and none of them working totally correctly, I tried a two column table.  Using that the width of the two elements don't need to be specified, the second element never appears below the first, and scrollbars are added as needed, with the right column content never being cut off and unscrollable.

Thanks everyone for your help.  I must say, I feel in some cases the "generation 2" css spec with the addition of the floating layouts, really has made things unnecessarily complex to use, if it can even work at all, e.g. like in my case, where I don't know the content of the right column (as this page is a template, holding variable right column content).  In this case, I could not get any of the answers to work, with the closest being Ryan's, but in some cases the content at the right would get clipped off, and was not scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to avoid this, without assigning a width?

No.

> If not, what is the least width spec's I need to add? I.e. can I assign a fixed pixel width to the left column, and have the right column get the rest?

Yes.

Comment: Ryan, what do I assign the second main column, if I assign a width like 150px to the left column?  Note I've got various content coming into the main column, don't know it's width, just want it to sit to the side of the left (nav) column.

Comment: You don't need to assign a width to the right column. You may want to assign `overflow: hidden`, to it though. In most browsers, that will keep it from wrapping under the left column.

Comment: Hmm, didn't work in Firefox or Chrome  (i.e. adding overflow: hidden).  The right (main content) column is still wrapping underneath.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that's helpful.  Can you tell me why in the first part of this, the right column folds underneath the left, and has no border between.  I.e. what is different in the second part, such that it has a border, and this doesn't occur, as both parts are using class="left" and class="right"?

Comment: ... I guess in the second case, the whole outside container is picking up "overflow: hidden".  Would this affect the border display though?

Comment: Both of them have a border. It's just hard to see against the edge of the window in the first example. Applying `overflow: hidden` to `.right` in the second example prevents the content from folding under the left.

Comment: I see, overflow:hidden and matching the margin-left to be the same percentage as the width of the left column.  There must be another facet too, of not assigning float:left to the right column?  In the case of my current right panel content, I have a table there, and the overflow:hidden is cutting off the content entirely, instead of getting a scrollbar at the bottom of the browser.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for your help!  Since the solution you gave ended up cutting my variable content (in this case a table), I decided to use a two column table to do the left and right columns.  In some cases, trying to use the CSS float layout capabilities really seem like a pain/step backward from basic tables.  Thoughts / comments?

Comment: @Ray: indeed, it's quite silly that CSS forces you to declare the width of the left column. http://giveupandusetables.com/

Answer (score 1):

Widths and margins are the only thing that will prevent your main content from being pushed under the far left item. Once the elements touch <-- the second ('main' in your case) is getting pushed to the next line - that is the proper document flow.

Try using min/max widths, percentages or a combination of the two, if you don't want to commit to pixels.

**EDITED FOR ILLUSTRATIVE PURPOSES**

```
<div id="parent_left"> <-- { width:15% }
    <div id="fixed_width_child></div>
</div>
<div id="parent_main"> <-- { width:85% }
    <div id="dynamic_width_child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dawson.  I can commit to a width of the left (nav) column, but the main content will be variable in size, coming from different sources.  Do you know how I can do this then, i.e. give the left it's size, and have the right be variable?  If I assign a percentage, say 15% and 85%, and the right content is small, then ?

Comment: No problem. Make the right content a container (parent) - perhaps the left as well, if that makes things easier. At that point, your right side would always be "85%", even if its visible content was 22px wide.

Comment: I'm not getting you, what do you mean by "container (parent)"?  Right now they are both divs, one below each other, which the first div having a width of 15%, and the second div having a width of 85%, both with float:left.  Main still going under left.

Comment: @Ray - Answer edited to illustrate the idea. It's called nesting. I'm not an advocate, but it is required sometimes. In this case, the first container is fixed width - so styling it for content would work (in other words, not making it a parent). The main content, however, might work best as a container/parent since its content's width is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want, two columns, both re-size:

http://glish.com/css/9.asp

Comment: Thanks Steve, is this page broken in your browser too -- i.e. the example doesn't show?